# How could I message a dumb phone and an iPad at the same time

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, sms

I have an iPhone and my friend has a regular old dumb phone and an iPad.  At school, she has no cell service, but she does have wifi on her iPad.  Everywhere else she has her phone, but doesn't carry her iPad, so I have no idea which device to message.

Is there an app or service I could use that would message both at once and keep the conversation intact on all of our devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Groupme](http://www.groupme.com) is a handy group/topical message app that allows you to create "groups" like "My family", "Pictures of Griffin", "My Bocce Discussion Group" on the fly.

You can access it through a web client, or through dedicated iOS and android apps.

Each group is essentially a private chat room for the people you invite, who can post messages, locations, or pictures that the entire group can see.

It's much more useful than I'd have guessed when you have a group that shares an interest or temporal event (it's awesome for people at a wedding or bachelor party to keep track of what everyone's up to.)

(If you ever used Beluga before Facebook ingested it, it's basically the same thing.)

Comment: Yeah, this is great.  Little wonky setting up just a group of two, but this is rad.  You can message from the web too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can send a text message to multiple recipients at once with the built-in Messages app. Just send a message to both her cellphone's number and her iPad's email address.

Comment: I should have been clearer.  Ideally, I'm hoping for a system where I can send messages to "Jane" and not care what device she's using.  In this senario, her reply won't stay in context of what I sent to her.  However, this could be a simple option.